# combine `find -printf` and `find -exec grep -l`

Tags: bash, find

How can I `find` files that contain specific content (`grep`able) and sort the found files by last modified time? (I want to select just the one newest file)

This command finds files:

```
find subfolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -l 'blue_wizards' {} \;`
```

This command finds files and sort them:

```
find subfolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort
```

But if I supply `-printf` the input to `-exec grep` will be not what I want.

Comment: Do you only  want to see a list of matching files sorted by modification time or  do you also want to see the last modification time of each file?

Comment: I just want to select 1 file, the one latest modified. So modification time is not interesting to see, it's just the sorting condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to use `zsh` and its glob qualifiers:

```
grep -le blue_wizards -- subfolder/*(D.Om)
```

Where:

- `D` also includes hidden files like `find` does by default
- `.` restricts to regular files (like `-type f`)
- `Om` sorts in reverse by age like `ls -rt` with oldest file first

You can do the same with GNU `find`, `cut` and `xargs` with any Bourne-like shell with:

```
find subfolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zn |
  cut -zf2- |
  xargs -r0 grep -le blue_wizards --
```

With older versions of GNU `cut`, you may need to use `tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | cut -f2- | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'` instead or resort to GNU `sed` which, like GNU `sort` has been supporting `-z` for much longer: `LC_ALL=C sed -z 's/^[^:]*://'` (and change the `\t` to `:` in the `-printf` argument).

Note that in any case. `-printf` is GNU-specific (`-maxdepth` is also a GNU extension, though now supported by more `find` implementations).

`%T@` is better than `%T+` as it avoids computing the calendar date for the corresponding mtime, but also more importantly because it works correctly around DST changes. If using `%T+` for sorting, you'd want to fix `TZ` to UTC0 for instance to get UTC timestamps not affected by DST.

Compare:

```
$ ls --full-time -ldrt a b
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 13 2020-10-25 01:43:28.989189400 +0100 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 13 2020-10-25 01:31:20.112312300 +0000 a
$ find a b -printf '%T+ %T@ %p\n' | sort
2020-10-25+01:31:20.1123123000 1603589480.1123123000 a
2020-10-25+01:43:28.9891894000 1603586608.9891894000 b
$ TZ=UTC0 find a b -printf '%T+ %T@ %p\n' | sort
2020-10-25+00:43:28.9891894000 1603586608.9891894000 b
2020-10-25+01:31:20.1123123000 1603589480.1123123000 a
```

`a` is newer than `b` even though it appears older with `%T+` as it was modified after the switch to winter time in my timezone (Europe/London here).

---

To get the newest file, you'd likely want to reverse that order (change `Om` to `om` and `sort` to `sort -r`) and get `grep` to output the list of files NUL-delimited instead of newline-delimited so it can reliably be post-processed (as newline is as valid a character as any in a file name), for which you'll need GNU `grep` or compatible and get the first one.

For instance to store the path of the newest file in the `$newest` variable (and return with a failure exit status if there's no matching file):

zsh + GNU grep:

```
grep --null -le blue_wizards -- subfolder/*(D.om) |
  IFS= read -rd '' newest
```

bash + GNU find + GNU sort + GNU cut + GNU xargs + GNU grep:

```
IFS= read -rd '' newest < <(
  find subfolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
    LC_ALL=C sort -rzn |
    cut -zf2- |
    xargs -r0 grep --null -le blue_wizards --
)
```

---

to get all of them (newest first) into an array:

zsh + GNU grep:

```
files=(${(0)"$(grep --null -le blue_wizards -- subfolder/*(D.om))"})
print -r newest: $files[1]
```

bash 4.4+ + GNU find + GNU sort + GNU cut + GNU xargs + GNU grep:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(
  find subfolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
    LC_ALL=C sort -rzn |
    cut -zf2- |
    xargs -r0 grep --null -le blue_wizards --
)
printf '%s\n' "newest: ${files[0]}"
```

---

If you wanted to do that POSIXly, that is only using standard sh and utility syntax (so without all the GNU or zsh extensions), it would be impossible to do it without making some assumptions on what byte values the file names may contain. If you can guarantee the file names don't contain newline characters and are reasonably short, you should be able to do:

```
dir=subfolder
file=$(
  export LC_ALL=C
  CDPATH= cd -P -- "$dir" &&
    ls -At |
      sed 's/"/"\\""/g; s/.*/"&"/; s|^|./|' |
      xargs -E '' sh -c '
        [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || 
          find "$@" -type f -exec grep -l blue_wizards {} +' sh |
      head -n 1
)
[ -n "$file" ] && newest="$dir/$file"
```

If you can make even more assumptions like the file names also only contain alnums, `.`, `-` characters from the portable character set, don't start with `-`, are all regular files, `$CDPATH` is not set, `$dir` doesn't contain `..`  components, doesn't start with `-` nor `+`:

```
dir=subfolder
file=$(
  cd "$dir" &&
    ls -At |
      xargs grep -l blue_wizards |
      head -n 1
)
[ -n "$file" ] && newest="$dir/$file"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest may be to combine both `find` commands like so:

```
find subfolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type f \
    -exec grep -q 'blue_wizards' {} \; \
    -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort
```

The thing here is that `-exec ;` can be used as a condition, it's truthy or falsy based on the exit status of the command. Also `grep -q` to just get the exit status, and no output.

That requires spawning a copy of `grep` for each file, so it's not exactly optimal in that. `-exec {} +` doesn't work the same way: you couldn't get exit statuses for the individual files that way, so it always evaluates as truthy. Also, with `-printf "%T+ %p\n"` you'll have issues if any filenames contain newlines.

Comment: See also the issue with using `%T+` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to combine them, but I must have been doing something wrong. I went with `find module_root/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -q '#%Module' {} \; -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -r | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2`

Comment: @Moberg, mm. I don't have your exact files of course, but I can't see immediately what would be wrong with that. It works for some test files I just made. Run it in smaller pieces, see if the `find` produces the right output, or even sees the right files etc.

Comment: AH sorry, it works great, thanks. What I mean was that my initial try that made me write the question didn't work. Now it works! :)

Comment: @Moberg, ah, ok!